# How can I go from current fragment to another at right way, using Yalantis SlideMenu?

Tags: java, android, github, material-design

Unfortunately, I am finding the developer of [this project](https://github.com/Yalantis/Side-Menu.Android/issues) doesn't reply at all. So I am posting here. I am trying to implement [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/Side-Menu.Android) UI on my project but developer has used image in sample code. I need to implement here a fragment from one to another. I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32512659/intent-to-activity-in-side-menu-android-of-material-design) but this doesn't change my fragment. Below is the code how I implemented.

Note: Below codes are a lot. I posted it to make sure where the problem was. As the documentation and sample project I did all well.

**activity_home.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<io.codetail.widget.RevealLinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/container1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/lightbrown"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2">

            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:id="@+id/textBoy"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="32dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:typeface="monospace"
                android:text="@string/boy"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:textSize="180sp"
                autofit:minTextSize="20sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/home_boy_one" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/lightGreen"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2">

            <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                android:id="@+id/textGirl"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_margin="32dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:typeface="monospace"
                android:text="@string/girl"
                android:textSize="180sp"
                autofit:minTextSize="20sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.8">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/home_girl_one" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</io.codetail.widget.RevealLinearLayout>
```

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends Fragment implements ScreenShotable {
    private View Fragmentone_view;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private AutofitTextView textBoy, textGirl;
    private Typeface typeface;

    @Nullable

    public static Home newInstance() {
        Home home = new Home();
        return home;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        textBoy = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textBoy);
        textGirl = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textGirl);
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/trench.otf");
        textBoy.setTypeface(typeface);
        textGirl.setTypeface(typeface);
        Log.d("reachHera","reachhere");
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void takeScreenShot() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(Fragmentone_view.getWidth(),
                            Fragmentone_view.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                    Fragmentone_view.draw(canvas);
                    Home.this.bitmap = bitmap;
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        this.Fragmentone_view = view.findViewById(R.id.container1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


}
```

**ContentFragment.java**

```
    public class ContentFragment extends Fragment implements ScreenShotable {
    public static final String CLOSE = "Close";
    public static final String BUILDING = "Building";
    public static final String BOOK = "Book";
    public static final String PAINT = "Paint";
    public static final String CASE = "Case";
    public static final String SHOP = "Shop";
    public static final String PARTY = "Party";
    public static final String MOVIE = "Movie";

    private View containerView;
    protected ImageView mImageView;
    protected int res;
    private Bitmap bitmap;

    public static ContentFragment newInstance(int resId) {
        ContentFragment contentFragment = new ContentFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(Integer.class.getName(), resId);
        contentFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return contentFragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        this.containerView = view.findViewById(R.id.container);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        res = getArguments().getInt(Integer.class.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        mImageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image_content);
        mImageView.setClickable(true);
        mImageView.setFocusable(true);
        mImageView.setImageResource(res);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void takeScreenShot() {
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(containerView.getWidth(),
                        containerView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
                containerView.draw(canvas);
                ContentFragment.this.bitmap = bitmap;
            }
        };

        thread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewAnimator.ViewAnimatorListener {
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private List<SlideMenuItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
private ContentFragment contentFragment;
private ViewAnimator viewAnimator;
private int res = R.drawable.content_music;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    contentFragment = ContentFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.content_music);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment)
            .commit();
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    });


    setActionBar();
    createMenuList();
    viewAnimator = new ViewAnimator<>(this, list, contentFragment, drawerLayout, this);
}

    private void createMenuList() {
        SlideMenuItem menuItem0 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.CLOSE, R.drawable.icn_close);
        list.add(menuItem0);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.BUILDING, R.drawable.icn_1);
        list.add(menuItem);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem2 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.BOOK, R.drawable.icn_2);
        list.add(menuItem2);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem3 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.PAINT, R.drawable.icn_3);
        list.add(menuItem3);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem4 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.CASE, R.drawable.icn_4);
        list.add(menuItem4);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem5 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.SHOP, R.drawable.icn_5);
        list.add(menuItem5);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem6 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.PARTY, R.drawable.icn_6);
        list.add(menuItem6);
        SlideMenuItem menuItem7 = new SlideMenuItem(ContentFragment.MOVIE, R.drawable.icn_7);
        list.add(menuItem7);
    }


    private void setActionBar() {
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,                  /* host Activity */
                drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
                toolbar,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
                R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
                R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
        ) {

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                linearLayout.removeAllViews();
                linearLayout.invalidate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                if (slideOffset > 0.6 && linearLayout.getChildCount() == 0)
                    viewAnimator.showMenuContent();
            }

            /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (drawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_settings:
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    private ScreenShotable replaceFragment(ScreenShotable screenShotable, int topPosition) {
        View view = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
        int finalRadius = Math.max(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
        SupportAnimator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, 0, topPosition, 0, finalRadius);
        animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        animator.setDuration(ViewAnimator.CIRCULAR_REVEAL_ANIMATION_DURATION);

        findViewById(R.id.content_overlay).setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), screenShotable.getBitmap()));
        animator.start();
//        ContentFragment contentFragment = ContentFragment.newInstance(this.res);
//        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment).commit();
        return screenShotable;
        }

    @Override
    public ScreenShotable onSwitch(Resourceble slideMenuItem, ScreenShotable screenShotable, int position) {
        switch (slideMenuItem.getName()) {
            case ContentFragment.CLOSE:
                return screenShotable;
            case ContentFragment.BOOK:
                Toast.makeText(this, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Home home=Home.newInstance();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,home);
                return replaceFragment(home,position);

                default:
                return replaceFragment(screenShotable, position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void disableHomeButton() {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

    }

    @Override
    public void enableHomeButton() {
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

    }

    @Override
    public void addViewToContainer(View view) {
        linearLayout.addView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: In the last link in your question there is a answer to your question and you didn't implement it in the code you provided.

Comment: @H.Brooks of course i implemented. See my MainActivity.java used switch and Case ContentFragment.BOOK : however this code exectues with toast but fragment remains same (contentfragment ) which is defult which i run on the top of the code.